# How to use EXTJS in a django app?

Tags: javascript, django, extjs

I have an django-driven web app that displays ExtJS components.  I want to show or hide an ExtJS panel based on some django template logic.  This isn't working and I can't figure out how to do this.

Here's what I tried (Letter map to code below):
A.    I tried to put template logic in my js file.  Big fail... This pretty much corrupted my js.

B.    I tried to build the extjs gui then hide the panel.  I either get a null or undefined error based depending on the method I tried.    I suspect a sequence problem here, but I don't know how to confirm that.

What is the proper way to hide/unhide an EXTJS component based on django template logic?  How can I make this work?

Below is my code snippets:

```
--------------------------
//////////Javascript Start ///////////// 
   //A. Tried to wrap with {% if X %}
   var myPanel= {
      xtype : 'panel',
      title : 'My Panel',
      id : 'myPanel',
      height : 100,
      width : 100,
      hideable: true,
      html : 'Hello!'
    }
///////////Javascript End////////////

<html>
<head>
   <!-- references above javascript -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
... body stuff...    

 <script type="text/javascript">
   <!--  B Tried to a map an EXTJS hide statement with django -->
   {% if X %}
     Ext.get('myPanel').hide();  // Null Error
     Ext.getCmp('myPanel').hide(); // Undefined Error
     Ext.getCmp("myPanel").hide(); // Undefined Error
   {% endif %}
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use '101010' option in the editor to post the code, its not readable in the current format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue #1 - You're not rendering your panel in the first place, you're just creating a Javascript object.

Issue #2 - You're not delaying your javascript execution until the DOM is ready, so when you fix #1, you're still going to error out.

Try adding a `<div id="panel-container"></div>` to your body content, wherever you want the panel rendered.  Then, do something like this in your javascript file:

```
//create a global namespace for stuff that exists in your application.
Ext.ns('YourAppName'); 

//run this code once the DOM is loaded:
Ext.onReady(function(){  // run this function once the DOM is loaded, not before!
    YourAppName.myPanel= new Ext.Panel({
        title : 'My Panel',
        id : 'myPanel',
        height : 100,
        width : 100,
        hideable: true,
        html : 'Hello!',
        renderTo:'panel-container'  // Tells the panel where it ought to appear in the DOM
    });
});
```

Then, in your document, leverage Ext.onReady again:

```
{% if X %}
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function(){
    YourAppName.myPanel.hide();
});    
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense.  So I tried it and I am getting an error "YourAppName.myPanel.hide is not a function"   How do I know if the function is defined before its getting called?

Comment: Well, my code is lacking something obvious -- it's never actually creating the panel.  See my edit in a minute.

Comment: I edited my answer to be correct.  Another problem you were having is that you weren't actually instantiating an panel anywhere -- your original code just defines a plain object with configuration values.  You include an xtype, but that won't cause anything to happen unless you feed that configuration object into some ExtJS Component.  I've changed my answer to illustrate directly creating a panel.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked and really helped me understand better how this works.